# What is the equivalent of Mage::app()->getResponse() in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

We have a code `Mage::app()->getResponse()` in Magento1

> \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve response object
 *
 * @return Zend_Controller_Response_Http
 */
public function getResponse()
{
    if (empty($this->_response)) {
        $this->_response = new Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http();
        $this->_response->headersSentThrowsException = Mage::$headersSentThrowsException;
        $this->_response->setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    }
    return $this->_response;
```

What is the equivalent code in Magento2 ? I want to use it in a observer.

I have a code snippet in the Magento1 like following.

```
if (!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   if ($action != 'noRoute') {
            $customerSession->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('business')->__('some text'));
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('business/portal/login', array('access' => 'denied')), 403);
        die(Mage::app()->getResponse());
 }
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about how you need to use the response.

Comment: @SergeyIvashchenko Please check the updated question

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps!!

```
class Classname implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http
     */
    protected $response;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response
    )
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }


   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $item_url = $observer->getEvent()->getData('url');       
    $this->response->setRedirect($item_url ); 

    }
}
?>
```

You can change the function as per your need.. Its just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your url inside **setRedirect()**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getBaseUrl().'business/portal/login');

    return $this;
}
```